# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities Exception

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I got a exception while implementing the following statements.

```
 DateTime result;
 if (!DateTime.TryParse(rule.data, out result))
     return jobdescriptions;
 if (result < new DateTime(1754, 1, 1)) // sql can't handle dates before 1-1-1753
     return jobdescriptions;
 return jobdescriptions.Where(j => j.JobDeadline.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data).Date );
```

**Exception**

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

I know what the exception means but i don't know how to get rid of it. Any help?

Comment: This is in EF6 and lower. EF core supports `.Date`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

LINQ to Entities cannot translate most .NET Date methods (including the casting you used) into SQL since there is no equivalent SQL.

The solution is to use the Date methods outside the LINQ statement and then pass in a value. It looks as if Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data).Date is causing the error.

Calling Date on a DateTime property also cannot be translated to SQL, so a  workaround is to compare the .Year .Month and .Day properties which can be translated to LINQ since they are only integers.

```
var ruleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data).Date;
return jobdescriptions.Where(j => j.Deadline.Year == ruleDate.Year 
                       && j.Deadline.Month == ruleDate.Month 
                       && j.Deadline.Day == ruleDate.Day);
```

Comment: What about j => `j.JobDeadline.Date` ?

Comment: Is Date a property on JobDeadline ? This shouldn't cause an error by itself - perhaps a naming conflict (but not sure on this). If the line is still causing an error just rename it DeadlineDate or similar.

Comment: Date is property on JobDeadline. JobDeadline is DateTime type of which i want to extract Date.

Comment: Then, to work this within LINQ you would need to just compare JobDeadline property, eg j.JobDeadline > ruleDate. This needs a bit of testing but can be made to work. Alternatively compare the three properties of .Month .Day and .Year (j.Deadline.Year == ruleDate.Year && j j.Deadline.Month == ruleDate.Month &&  j.Deadline.Day == ruleDate.Day). Not elegant but it works since these are only integers.

Comment: Hmm. This idea works. Dirty but works. If you write it as answer i can mark it correct.

Comment: Update the Answer. Definitely a workaround, Im sure the EF team will plug this gap. Will try update this when they do, but for now it at least works.

Comment: @Slauma's answer is better. You should change the accepted answer to that.

Comment: This is the best approach to compare dates IMO since I can compare in a Service layer rather than doing it in a Repository layer with the EF Truncate method.

Answer (score 240):

You can use the [**TruncateTime**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method of the [**EntityFunctions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) to achieve a correct translations of the `Date` property into SQL:

```
using System.Data.Objects; // you need this namespace for EntityFunctions

// ...

DateTime ruleData = Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data).Date;
return jobdescriptions
    .Where(j => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(j.JobDeadline) == ruleData);
```

**Update:** `EntityFunctions`is deprecated in EF6, Use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

Comment: Well, i noticed that `ruleData` is `DateTime` type and `j.JobDeadline` has truncatedtime. Doesn't feel right. Didn't get exception but didn't get expected result as well.

Comment: @aneal: It returns all records where `JobDeadline` has the same *date* as `rule.data`, no matter what's the *time of the day*. Isn't that what you want to achieve with your query in the question? Why doesn't it feel right?

Comment: `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(j.JobDeadline) == ruleData` condition is never satisfied, though the date are same.

Comment: @aneal: Did you add the **.Date** after Convert.... as shown in my answer? `DateTime ruleData = Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data).Date`. `.Date` truncates the time as well, so both sides of the comparison are a date with time `00:00:00`. For me it works this way, I've tested it.

Comment: I did add the .Date property. The time for ruleData is shown as `12:00:00`

Comment: @aneal: That's confusing. Obviously `12:00:00` is midnight representation in your locale. I hadn't expect that the comparison is dependent of a locale format (midnight is midnight). Can you try to use the `TruncateTime` on the right side of the comparison as well, so: `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(j.JobDeadline) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(ruleData)`

Comment: +1 and i agree with above, is definitely a better answer for 99% of implementations

Comment: Note that `EntityFunctions` is deprecated in EF6, you should now use `DbFunctions`.

Comment: The bad of this approach is when you're querying data in a Service layer and don't have access to Entity Framework methods, which is located at other layer (Repository).

Comment: But why can't we compare the inequality by `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(j.JobDeadline) > ruleData

Comment: this answer should be the correct marked answer, shame it isn't.

Comment: Namespace for DbFunctions in > EF6 is `System.Data.Entity` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn220142(v=VS.113).aspx

Comment: seems like `TruncateTime` (and some more important methods) are **not** implemented in `MySQL`. see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714022/canonical-function-entityfunctions-truncatetime-does-not-exist-in-mysql) for a custom `FUNCTION` to add to your DB.

Comment: Note that DbFunction will not work with mocking framework such as moq and it will give exception as "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities." so @Judo answer is the workaround.

Answer (score 40):

For EF6 use DbFunctions.TruncateTime(mydate) instead.

Answer (score 10):

"EntityFunctions.TruncateTime" or "DbFunctions.TruncateTime" in ef6 Is Working but it has some performance issue in Big Data.

I think the best way is to act like this:

```
DateTime ruleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rule.data);

DateTime  startDate = SearchDate.Date;

DateTime  endDate = SearchDate.Date.AddDay(1);

return jobdescriptions.Where(j.Deadline >= startDate 
                       && j.Deadline < endDate );
```

it is better than using parts of the date to. because query is run faster in large data.

Comment: +1 for this answer. `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` (later replaced by `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`) are implemented by converting to SQL where the datetime is converted to a string and that is truncated. This makes the query run significantly slower, in proportion to the number of records processed.

Answer (score 3):

Need to include `using System.Data.Entity;`. Works well even with `ProjectTo<>`

```
var ruleDate = rule.data.Date;
return jobdescriptions.Where(j => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(j.Deadline) == ruleDate);
```

Comment: As was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600750/861716)

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that LINQ to SQL doesn't know how to turn the `Date` property into a SQL expression. This is because the `Date` property of the `DateTime` structure has no analog in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

**It worked for me.**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
var ord = db.Orders.Where
      (p => p.UserID == User && p.ValidityExpiry <= dt);
```

Source: [Asp.net Forums](https://forums.asp.net/post/4934580.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I work with DateTime-Ranges.
My solution is to manipulate the start-time (with any date) to 00:00:00 
and the end-time to 23:59:59
So I must no more convert my DateTime to Date, rather it stays DateTime.

If you have just one DateTime, you can also set the start-time (with any date) to 00:00:00 and the end-time to 23:59:59
Then you search as if it were a time span.

```
var from = this.setStartTime(yourDateTime);
var to = this.setEndTime(yourDateTime);

yourFilter = yourFilter.And(f => f.YourDateTime.Value >= from && f.YourDateTime.Value <= to);
```

Your can do it also with DateTime-Range:

```
var from = this.setStartTime(yourStartDateTime);
var to = this.setEndTime(yourEndDateTime);

yourFilter = yourFilter.And(f => f.YourDateTime.Value >= from && f.YourDateTime.Value <= to);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by many here, using the TruncateTime function is slow.

Easiest option if you can is to use EF Core. It can do this. If you can't then a better alternative to truncate is to not change the queried field at all, but modify the bounds. If you are doing a normal 'between' type query where the lower and upper bounds are optional, the following will do the trick.

```
    public Expression<Func<PurchaseOrder, bool>> GetDateFilter(DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
    {
        var dtMinDate = (StartDate ?? SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value).Date;
        var dtMaxDate = (EndDate == null || EndDate.Value == SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value) ? SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value : EndDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1);
        return x => x.PoDate != null && x.PoDate.Value >= dtMinDate && x.PoDate.Value < dtMaxDate;
    }
```

Basically, rather than trimming PoDate back to just the Date part, we increment the upper query bound and user < instead of <=