# How to search date using nullable datetime?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<database_WICs> GetDate(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        var data = from c in db.database_WICs
                   where c.UploadDate.Value.Date <= start &&
                   c.UploadDate.Value.Date >= end
                   select c;
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

I am currently experiencing "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" exceptional error, using the following query string: api/data?start=25/11/2013&end=28/11/2013

I am novice programming student so please excuse my knowledge and silly mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597373/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-exception)? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601676/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-init) one?

Comment: thanks for your quick response and helpful links. I shall give this another try. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TruncateTime` method as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<database_WICs> GetDate(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start).Date;
    DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(end).Date;
    var data = from c in db.database_WICs
               Where(c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.UploadDate) <= startDate
                 &&  c => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.UploadDate) >= endDate)
               Select c;
    return data.ToList();
}
```