# asp.net mvc select with date in Linq to entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

i have a problem in in Linq to entity when selecting this is my code

i want to select with date and id

```
    Login Lo = new Login();
    DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;         
    Lo = db.Logins.Where(i => i.Emp_id == employee.id &&
     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.WorkDay).Value.Date == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(CurrentDate).Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

it give me this Error :

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Comment: please see this q&a for the same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597373/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-exception

Comment: LINQ to Entities basically translates your expression in to a SQL statement.  It doesn't know how to convert Date operations.  You'll need to create them as string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for helping i found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you could do this:

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;   
var result= db.Logins.Where(i => i.Emp_id == employee.id &&
                                 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.WorkDay) == currentDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your issue is because the Linq to Entities provider can't translate the operations that are defined in the `Date` property to a proper expression in SQL:

```
    // Returns the date part of this DateTime. The resulting value
    // corresponds to this DateTime with the time-of-day part set to
    // zero (midnight).
    //
    public DateTime Date {
        get { 
            Int64 ticks = InternalTicks;
            return new DateTime((UInt64)(ticks - ticks % TicksPerDay) | InternalKind);
        }
    }
```

That's why my advice is, outside of your query, call `Date` property from `DateTime.Now`, this way you will get the current date without the time part, and in your query, you don't need to call `Date` property, that's the function of `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` method