# LINQ and order-by a date field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've a very simple LINQ query to select dates from a table column - and I want to order by the date values:

```
var allDates = db.Table1.Select(m => m.Date).OrderBy(m => m.Date).Distinct();
```

But during runtime, I get the exception

```
"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."
```

In the model and the database, date-field is of type "DateTime".
Selecting the values without ordering works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting only the `Date` column, then you are trying to order by the property `Date` of this `Date`.

Instead:

```
var allDates = db.Table1.OrderBy(x => x.Date).Select(x => x.Date).Distinct();
```

or

```
var allDates = db.Table1.Select(x => x.Date).OrderBy(date => date).Distinct();
```

The order doesn't matter.

---

**Update**: Linq-To-Entities doesn't [support the `Date` property of `DateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597373/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-exception)

If you need to truncate the time and you want to order by the date only, you could use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`:

```
var allDates = db.Table1.Select(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date)).OrderBy(dt => dt).Distinct();
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `DateTime` has `Date` property, but it is not supported in *Linq to Entities*

Comment: @AdilMammadov: i need coffee :D

Comment: afaik that's it. you need to use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Date)` for it

Comment: Thank you so much ... wow and so fast :-) ... The hint with the truncated time is a nice addon I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

as in question [The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601676/the-specified-type-member-date-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-init)

> DateTime.Date cannot be converted to SQL. Use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime method to get date part.

take a look at something like this:

```
var allDates = db.Table1.Select(m => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.Date)).OrderBy(date => date).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
var allDates = db.Table1.Select(m => m.Date).OrderBy(m => m.Value.Year)
                         .ThenBy(m => m.Value.Month)
                         .ThenBy(m => m.Value.Day).Distinct();
```